# What is the most efficient way to retrieve an element from a multidimensional array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Let's assume I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
CURRENCIES = [
  [ "EUR", "€" ],
  [ "USD", "$" ],
  [ "GBP", "£" ]
]
```

What is the most efficient way in Ruby to retrieve a currency symbol by providing a currency code?

Comment: why trivial `Hash[CURRENCIES]["EUR"]` is not good enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert it to hash:

```
currencies_hash = Hash[CURRENCIES]
```

and then get what you need:

```
currencies_hash["EUR"] #=>"€"
```

i don't know if it is most efficient (for memory usage or CPU Time or ?..) but Ruby-style elegant enough =)

and if you can define CURRENCIES as a hash then you do not need an array

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to convert those nested arrays into a hash programmatically, but if you do, here's how you would do that.

```
def hash(a)
   h = {}
   a.each { |x| h[x[0]] = x[1] }
   h
end

CURRENCIES = hash(your_array)
```